# Difficulties saving URL from Chrome tab (for Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to build a Chrome extension which will check (through a "link:URL" Google search) which sites link to the one that is currently open in the active tab. But my code fails to properly save the tab's URL into a variable. I have found similar questions (and their answers) here on stackoverflow and I understand it may have sth to do with the fact that js is asynchronous, but I wasn't able to make it work. Any hint(s) would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!

```
// this is the part that doesn't work

chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (tabs) {
  var query = tabs[0].url;
  });

// this is the part that works just fine

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{

    var stemURL = "http://www.google.com/#q=link:";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: (stemURL + query) });
});
```

Here's how I set the permissions in the manifest, which should be right

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
```

Comment: You might have some troubles with Google's search results for your extension; it gives you different results depending on whether or not you put a space after the colon in "link:". ([Source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/Y-cqCyEBp8Y))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when you declare your "query" variable, it only has scope within your callback function in chrome.tabs.query. Now, you could declare your variable at the top of your script to give it scope within the entire script:

```
var query;
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (tabs) {
  query = tabs[0].url;
  });
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var stemURL = "http://www.google.com/#q=link:";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: (stemURL + query) });
});
```

...or you could use your activeTab variable that chrome.browserAction.onClick passes to you and grab the active tab's URL from that to ensure that you open the search results for the tab that the user was viewing when they clicked your extension's button, which would also have the added advantage of cutting out the first half of your code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var stemURL = "http://www.google.com/#q=link:";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: (stemURL + activeTab.url) });
});
```

I would recommend the latter approach; it's faster, cleaner, and more reliable. Good luck!